# Quantum Brain Dynamics and brain-physics questions

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions concerning [Quantum Brain Dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_brain_dynamics) theories or questions regarding physics used for analysis of the brain (example: applications of classical EM field theory in brain or other areas of physics involved with the brain) on-topic at Phys.SE, or should questions like this go to cognitive science?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like anything else that's multidisciplinary in nature, **it will depend on the question**.

However, some guidelines:

1. If it is about the *physics* of what is going on, it's fine to post here.
2. If it is about the *implications* or *results* of the physics (ie. biological/chemical response, metaphysical implications, etc) then it should not be here.

So without seeing the actual text of a question, we can't say. But so long as it is about the physics of the problem and not something like "How does the brain form memories under the theory of Quantum Brain Dynamics" it is possibly on-topic.